# C# Parsing Json Array

Tags: c#, json

I'm new to C#, I'm calling a service that is returning an encoded json response :

```
{"GetResult":["123"]}
```

In my code, I want to get 123. I wrote the following :

```
String response_after_parsing = JObject.Parse(response).SelectToken("GetResult").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(response_after_parsing);
```

The string that's being displayed in the console is the following :

```
["123"]
```

I've searched about this issue but I couldn't find the solution, any help please ?

Comment: `SelectToken("GetResult")` you're selecting the content of this key, so the return is correct

Comment: Yes but I only want 123 not ["123"]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Treat it like an array and you will be OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetResult` is an array so you need to access individual items within it:

```
var response_after_parsing = JObject.Parse(response).SelectToken("GetResult")[0].ToString();
```

Alternatively you may use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` but again access individual items within the array:

```
var response_after_parsing = ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response)).GetResult[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var response_after_parsing = JObject.Parse("{'GetResult':['123']}");
        var data =response_after_parsing["GetResult"][0]; // use like this
```

or

```
        var response_after_parsing = JObject.Parse(response).SelectToken("GetResult[0]").ToString();
```